# Check if a keyword is present in a column of strings

Tags: python, r

Lets say I have a dataframe df which is like this

```
    string
This is a cat
cat is crazy
it drinks milk
```

and lets us have another dataset like this having keyword and a tag assigned to it

```
 keyword     tag
     cat        43
     dog        34
    crazy       40
```

So I need to check whether the keywords are present in those strings and I need to tag them accordingly. So the output is like this

```
 string        keywords_matched      tag
This is a cat      cat                 43
cat is crazy       cat                 43
cat is crazy       crazy               40
```

Can anybody solve this using R or python ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In 'tidyverse' 'unnest' can help:

```
string<-c(
"This is a cat",
"cat is crazy",
"it drinks milk")
string <-as.data.frame(string)

df <- read.table(text=
"keyword     tag
 cat        43
 dog        34
crazy       40",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


string %>% mutate(keyword_matched=str_split(string,' ')) %>%
  unnest %>% 
  inner_join(df,by=c("keyword_matched"="keyword"))

#         string keyword_matched tag
#1 This is a cat             cat  43
#2  cat is crazy             cat  43
#3  cat is crazy           crazy  40
```

Comment: Hi,
I'm not getting the result.

This is the output I'm getting 

[1] sent            keyword_matched Section        
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Comment: I tried the code (copy and paste) on several versions of R :without any problem. My versions of the implied packages were : tidyr_0.7.1   dplyr_0.7.4   stringr_1.2.0

Answer (score 1):

This is the **Python version** of answer to your Question. This is **not** the most **efficient** way to do it but it will do the work as required.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(["This is a cat", "cat is crazy", "it drinks milk"], columns=["string"])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(["cat", "dog", "crazy"], columns=["keyword"])
df2['tag'] = pd.DataFrame([43, 34, 40])

cols=["string", "keywords_matched", "tags"]
my_values = []

for the_string in df1["string"]:
    for keyword, tag in df2.itertuples(index=False):
        if keyword in the_string:
            my_values.append([the_string, keyword, tag])
        else:
            pass

result = pd.DataFrame(my_values, columns=cols)
```

The logic applied is very simple. We just check if the *keyword* is present in the *string* by using a **nested for-loop** and then append the acquired result to a list and convert it into a **Dataframe**.

**Result:**

```
           string   keywords_matched    tags
0   This is a cat                cat      43
1    cat is crazy                cat      43
2    cat is crazy              crazy      40
```